# Are users notified when an app has been updated on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, notifications, upgrade

My questions:

1. Is users notified when an app has been updated on the App Store?
2. If so, how this notification is displayed?
3. How is this update performed on the phone? After user confirmation or automatically?

I'm an Android user. When an application has been updated on the Android Market, a notification is automatically shown in the status bar. Then, the user can click on it to open the Android Market app and list his applications. Finally, he can click on the "Update" button to upgrade them.

Comment: Isn't this kind off off-topic?

Comment: Well, it clarifies what needs to be done (or doesn't) when releasing an update.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I know my app will have to be upgraded periodically, so it's better to anticipate the update procedure. I'm sure it's a stupid question for an iPhone user but don't forget I'm an Android user, not iPhone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iTunes, a bubble with the number of updates available is displayed:
[image: iTunes sshot]

On the iPhone, update notifications are available on the App Store app:
[image: iPhone sshot]
<sub>(source: [iphoneincanada.ca](http://cdn.iphoneincanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/app_store_update_fail.jpg))</sub>

The user must choose to update by taping on 'Update all' or by choosing individually which apps to update.

Comment: Nice answer with the screenshots. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, via the App Store application and the iTunes desktop application.
2. On the iOS devices, a red notification icon will appear over the App Store application icon with the number of applications ready to be updaed. In iTunes, a similar thing in the Apps sidebar.
3. On the device, after user confirmation, the App Store app opens. In iTunes, the user is directed to the iTunes Store Updates page, where they can select Update All, or select individual applications to update.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, they are
2. It displays as a red notice icon on the app store app
3. The user must update the app manually through the app store.  It happens after user confirmation.